# Detect method's origin when parsing it's metadata in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, oop, metadata

I have code that parses metadata of a Qt plugin that I wrote which exposes some functionality via its interface. My plugin's main class inherits from QObject, so when I am reading the metadata, I also get the methods that are declared and publicly available in QObject, among them:

```
destroyed(Object *);
objectNameChanged(QString);
etc...
```

I want to only parse the methods are introduced in my plugin's main class, and not the methods that have been inherited from QObject, but looking at the properties that QMetaMethod provides, I don't see a way. I just have access to all methods from QMetaObject which include QObject's methods as well.

One way to solve this is also parse the metadata of QObject exclude it's methods from my plugin's main class. That is my last resort. I was wondering if Qt provides something out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`QMetaObject::methodOffset()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#methodOffset) method to get the index where the current class' methods start, and then iterate from there rather than starting at index 0:

```
const QMetaObject *object = metaObject();

// Gets only methods on the actual class.
for (int i = object->methodOffset(); i < object->methodCount(); ++i) {
    qDebug() << object->method(i).methodSignature();
}

// Gets all methods, including super classes.
for (int i = 0; i < object->methodCount(); ++i) {
    qDebug() << object->method(i).methodSignature();
}
```

This works because the method numbering is ordered so that all super/parent class methods come before the child class methods. Therefore, if you start at the offset where the child class methods start, you will skip all the super class methods.